# Signals.py file not being recognized in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-signals

I am working on follow/unfollow system and I need to add a signals.py file to make the follower count workl, but after I started investigating, I realized that the signals.py file was not being called because it is not on the *pycache* folder of the app. What can I do to make this file be recognized by django??

[image]

apps.py (this is what I tried)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts'
    def ready(self):
        import accounts.signals
```

If you need to see more code or have any questions please let me know in the comments;)

Comment: You need to import it, for example in the `AppConfig` of the app.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just added what I have on the apps.py file which is not working:(

Comment: did you register the `AccountsConfig` as default `AppConfig`, and added the app to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the module. For example in the `AppConfig`. In the `apps.py` you can specify an [**`AppConfig`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig), and load the signals with:

```
# accounts/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    
    # …

    def ready(self):
        from accounts import signals  # noqa
```

In the `__init__.py` you also should set this as the default `AppConfig`:

```
# accounts/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig'
```